# Loading dependency graph...jest-haste-map: Watchman crawl failed

Tags: react-native, expo, watchman

I cannot just create an empty project with "react-native init AwesomeProject" and "react-native run-ios". I'm getting the below error. This also happens when I use EXPO with Bare Workflow.

watchman -v: 4.9.0

My package.json says: "react-native": "0.59.9"

Any help? I've seen many similar issues on the web but none of the suggested solutions worked for me.

```
    Loading dependency graph...jest-haste-map: Watchman crawl failed. Retrying once with node crawler.
    Usually this happens when watchman isn't running. Create an empty `.watchmanconfig` file in your project's root folder or initialize a git or hg repository in your project.
    Error: Watchman error: The watchman connection was closed. Make sure watchman is running for this project. See https://facebook.github.io/watchman/docs/troubleshooting.html.
events.js:167
    throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
    ^



Error: The watchman connection was closed
    at Client.cancelCommands ({mypath}/node_modules/fb-watchman/index.js:52:15)
    at Socket.<anonymous> ({mypath}/node_modules/fb-watchman/index.js:128:12)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:187:15)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1092:12)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
Emitted 'error' event at:
    at handleError ({mypath}/node_modules/metro/node_modules/jest-haste-map/build/lib/WatchmanWatcher.js:362:10)
    at Object.onWatchProject [as cb] ({mypath}/node_modules/metro/node_modules/jest-haste-map/build/lib/WatchmanWatcher.js:135:9)
    at {mypath}/node_modules/fb-watchman/index.js:66:9
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at Client.cancelCommands ({mypath}/node_modules/fb-watchman/index.js:65:8)
    at Socket.<anonymous> ({mypath}/node_modules/fb-watchman/index.js:128:12)
    [... lines matching original stack trace ...]
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
Process terminated. Press <enter> to close the window
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears to be a `watchman`-related error. If you didn't install `Watchman`,

Install through brew.

```
$ brew install rmtree
$ brew rmtree watchman
$ sudo rm -rf /usr/local/var/run/watchman
```

If it is already installed, try installing it manually after deleting it completely.

```
$ git clone https://github.com/facebook/watchman.git
$ cd watchman
$ git checkout v4.7.0  # the latest stable release
$ ./autogen.sh
$ ./configure
$ make
$ sudo make install
$ chmod 0700 /usr/local/var/run/watchman/<user>-state
```

Comment: autogen produces errors :(

./autogen.sh
./autogen.sh: line 9: aclocal: command not found
./autogen.sh: line 10: autoheader: command not found
./autogen.sh: line 11: automake: command not found
./autogen.sh: line 12: autoconf: command not found

Comment: This is due to you donot have auto tools installed in your system. You can get aclocal and autoheader etc...  by brew:

Comment: After that you should change directory the repository folder using `example: cd checkout` and only after that you should do `./configure`

Comment: `configure` is a file located in that repository and it's written in bash. You don't have any file named  `configure` in your home folder so that's why you have to cd on your repository folder.

Comment: "sudo make install" comment produces the following error. 
  CC       root/watchman-stat.o
root/stat.c:188:13: error: logical not is only applied to the left hand side of this bitwise operator [-Werror,-Wlogical-not-parentheses]
        if (!root->watcher_ops->flags & WATCHER_HAS_PER_FILE_NOTIFICATIONS) {

Comment: You can pass the `--enable-lenient` flag to configure to prevent warnings from being promoted to errors and that should let you make progress if you want to compile the code for yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question. The culprit turned out to be the `.watchmanconfig` file. The contents of that file was the following:

```
{"fsevents_latency": "0.01"}
```

I've changed the value from string to int, and now everything is working for me:

```
{"fsevents_latency": 0.01}
```

Answer (score 0):

For react-native projects, I went into System Preferences > Security & Privacy > Privacy > Full Disk Access and manually gave access permission to the following.

- watchman
- Android Studio
- Visual Studio Code(If running command from VS code)